# Spotting error in this solution: Solve for $x : [x] -2x= 4$

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

*Solution*: Let $x \in [ k, k+1).$for some integer $ k$

Then $ [ x] = k$ where $[.]$ is the greatest integer function

Therefore, $ k -2x = 4$

$ \implies x = \dfrac{k-4}{2} \in [k,k+1)$

Solving for $k$, we get $k= -4,-5$ and therefore, $ x \in [-5,-3)$

But the points $ -5, -4.25$ clearly do not satisfy the equation.

*Where is the error in this solution?* Thanks!

Comment: Um.... You have $x = \frac {k-4}2$.  You *do* have to solve that.  Concluding that $x=\frac {k-4}{2} \in [k, k+1)$ and therefore *EVERYTHING* in $[k, k+1)$ is a solution is like concluding $w = \pi \in [3, 4)$ and therefore every single number in $[3, 4)$ is equal to $\pi$ and wondering why $3.9$ does not equal $\pi$.

Comment: So if $k = -4, -5$  ***AND*** $x = \frac {k-4}2$ what is $x$ allowed to be?  Certainly not *everything* between $-5$ and $-3$.

Comment: $\implies$ does not mean $\Leftarrow$.   You figured that $[x]-2x=4 \implies x\in [-5,-3)$ which is true, but that does NOT mean $x\in [-5,3) \implies [x]-2x=4$.  But $x\in [-5,3)$ *AND* $x = \frac {k-4}2; k=-5, k=-4$ does mean something a *lot* more conclusive.

Answer (score 2):

You can set $x=k+r$ with $k\in\mathbb Z$ and $r\in[0,1)$

This is equivalent to your presentation, but easier to manipulate than keeping some $x$ and the equation becomes:

$\lfloor x\rfloor-2x=k-2(k+r)=-k-2r=4\quad$  therefore $2r$ is an integer

- $r=0\implies x=k=-4$
- $r=\frac 12\implies -k=4+2r=5$ and $x=-4.5$

Regarding your solution up to $k=-4,-5$ this seems correct. But how to you end up with $-5,-4.25$ after that ?

Reporting in $x=\frac{k-4}2$ you'll end up with $-4,-4.5$.

Comment: "But how to you end up with −5,−4.25 after that ?" The O.P. ended with the *conditional* that $x \in [-5, -3)$ and assumed that as that was a conclusion it was a *final* solution.  If $[x]-2x = 4\implies x\implies [-5,-3)$ which is true, the OP concluded that $x\in [-5,-3) \implies [x]-2=4$ which is, of course, dead wrong.   $-5$ and $-4.25$ were just two examples the OP picked.

Comment: ah ok, I get it now, unfortunate reasoning I might say.